# Problem with Android Studio in running Flutter project

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, gradle

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with Android Studio. I cannot run flutter projects. It returns the error showed in the picture.

Android Studio version: 3.6.3
Flutter version: 1.22.1 with Dart 2.10.1

The Error showed while executing main.dart:

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 41
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> FlutterPlugin

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

[Error message from main.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfTcE.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:
I had to delete the cache file from .gradle folder and run project. And it worked.

Directory of the cache file: C:\user(username)\ .gradle

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this error before and the solution that works for me is to clean the build folder by using

> flutter clean

and uninstall the app from emulator/connect to any other device

Answer (score 0):

I changed the virtual device's x86 image to x86_64 and the problem was solved. Still don't understand the underlying cause, but it worked.